# How to pass a custom class with JSON to Controller

Tags: c#, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, post

I have this two classes in JS:

```
class Puerta {
    constructor(nro, tipo) {
        this.nroPuerta = nro;
        this.tipoPuerta = tipo;
    }
}

class Controladora {
    constructor(ip, segundos, puertas) {
        this.ipControladora = ip;
        this.apuertaSegundosControladora = segundos;
        this.listaPuertas = puertas;
    }
}
```

I have this code, that pass ‘Controladora’ correctly, but without any element of the array of ‘Puertas’ in the class ‘Controladora’.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    var puertas = [];
    for(var i = 1;i<=3;i++){
        puertas.push(new Puerta(i,"String " + i);
    }
    var controladora = new Controladora("192.168.1.1", 30, puertas);
    $.ajax({
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Controladora/Prueba',
        data: JSON.stringify({ 'Controladora': controladora }),
        success: function () {
        },
        failure: function (response) {
        }
    });
});
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQdRD.png)

And in the Controller, I get ‘Controladora’ but listaPuertas is null.

What am I doing wrong? Missing something?

EDIT

This are the classes in C#:

```
public class Puerta
{
    public int nroPuerta{ get; set; }
    public string tipoPuerta { get; set; }
}

public class Controladora
{
    public string ipControladora { get; set; }
    public int apuertaSegundosControladora { get; set; }
    public List<Puerta> listaPuertas { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Show your controller method (not a link to an image) and the models your binding to in the question

Comment: Constructor of `Controladora` takes only two parameters, but you passing three, and uses `this.listaPuertas = []` which initilize empty array

Comment: I doubt about the way you serializing to JSON. I think it need to be like this: `data: JSON.stringify(controladora),`. Because your javascript classes need to be serialized successfully to the c# instance.

Comment: I tried that, it didn't work, every attribute was empty. That's why i'm doing it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current js code is sending the ajax data like the below structure

```
{
    "Controladora": {
        "ipControladora": "",
        "listaPuertas": [{  "nroPuerta":  1 },
                         {   "nroPuerta": 2 },
                         {   "nroPuerta": 3 }]
    }
}
```

Assuming your action method is accepting a parameter of type `Controladora` class

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Prueba(Controladora model)
{
    // to do : return something,
}
```

For model binding to work, you should be sending something like this

To do this, you simply need to send data which matches with the structure of your Controldaora class. No need to specify the parameter name in your json payload.

```
{
    "ipControladora": "",
    "listaPuertas": [{      "nroPuerta": 1      },
                     {      "nroPuerta": 1      }, 
                     {      "nroPuerta": 1      }]
}
```

The below code should do it.

```
var puertas = [];
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    puertas.push({ nroPuerta: 1 });
}
var d = { ipControladora: "192.168.1.1",
                     apuertaSegundosControladora :30,
                     listaPuertas: puertas };


$.ajax({
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    url: '@Url.Action("Prueba","Controladora")',
    data: JSON.stringify(d),
    success: function () {
    },
    failure: function (response) {
    }
});
```

I replaced the js classes with js objects. But if want to use ECMA 2015 javascript classes, use the same code from your question. It should work.

```
var puertas = [];
for(var i = 1;i<=3;i++){
    puertas.push(new Puerta(i,"Stringy " + i));
}
var d = new Controladora("192.168.1.1", 30, puertas);
$.ajax({
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    url: '@Url.Action("Prueba","Controladora")',
    data: JSON.stringify(d),
    success: function () {
    },
    failure: function (response) {
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, it work for me. But, if i want to have a js class 'Controladora' with an array of 'Puertas' and pass with JSON, that class to controller?